# OpenJFX instead OpenJDK

Tags: debian, java

System: Debian 11, 5.10.0-8-amd64

I have installed OpenJFX package in purpose to use it instead of OpenJDK.
Typing "java --version":

```
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-post-Debian-2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-post-Debian-2, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I would like to use openjfx but how to replace it?
OpenJFX is localisated in /usr/share/openjfx/lib.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

OpenJFX isn’t used *instead* of OpenJDK. It’s a framework which is built on top of OpenJDK; to use it, you need a program which relies on the OpenJFX framework, and you run that program using OpenJDK with OpenJFX installed and its modules enabled.

See [the OpenJFX documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) for details; the specifics will depend on your application, but an example could be

```
java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloWorld
```

Comment: How to add these modules?
Simply 
java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib --add-modules=javafx.base
doesn't work.

Comment: Have you read [the JavaFX documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx)? You need to specify the specific modules which the application needs (*e.g.* `javafx.controls`).